# Slow animations when debugger running

Tags: react-native

As it was discussed here (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5632) it seems that animations will be always slow when you have chrome debugger on. And, as it was said, you can switch on logs in console and don't use debugger.

But I wonder if there is any other solution? We are using redux and redux-logger, which is quite useful, but only if information about actions are collapsed in the first place. In console it will be all expanded, so it will be a lot harder to read logs.

So again, my question is - is there any other solution? I am mostly looking for some ideas. Even idea how to switch off transition animation when debugger is running would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from across the room!

Posting here for other people having similar issues, We've created a small project to redirect logcat stream to the chrome console. Includes free cat.

[Stick Kitten](https://github.com/gpEscrivo/stick_kitten)